# Moq How to bypass the call to base

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
public class MyClass: AbstractBase
{
    public override bool Init(IAppContext contextIn)
    {
        if (base.Init(contextIn))
        {
            //my code 
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class as given above and wanted to write a unit test for the Init method and have mocked the `IAppContext`. How can I use mock to bypass the call to base?

This is what i am doing:

```
Mock<IAppContext> mockContex = new Mock<IAppContext >();
MyClass myClassInstance - new MyClass ();
myClassInstance.Init(mockContex.object);
```

The `base.init` looks like:

```
public virtual bool Init(IAppContext context_in) 
{
    if (context_in == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context_in", "IAppContext argument s null"); 
    } 
    this.myCommunication = context_in.getInterface<ICommunication>();
    if (this.myCommunication == null)
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("myCommunication", "ICommunication argument is null");
    } 
    this.myStateManager = new IStateManager(this.myCommunication);
    if (this.myStateManager == null)
    { 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create the State Manager");
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: You cannot bypass the call to base with Moq. What you can do is to setup `mockContex` in a way that `base.Init(contextIn)` returns true. Can you post how is `the base.Init` looks like?

Comment: public virtual bool Init(IAppContext context_in)
{  if (context_in == null)
{
throw new ArgumentNullException("context_in", (IAppContext argument s null");
}
this.myCommunication = context_in.getInterface<ICommunication>();
if (this.myCommunication == null)
{
throw new ArgumentNullException("myCommunication", "ICommunication argument is null");
}
this.myStateManager = new IStateManager(this.myCommunication);
if (this.myStateManager == null)
{
throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create the State Manager");
}
return true;
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your `IAppContext` mock in a way that `base.Init` will return true:

```
var communicationFake = new Mock<ICommunication>();
var appContextMock = new Mock<IAppContext>();

appContextMock
    .Setup(c => c.getInterface<ICommunication>())
    .Returns(communicationFake.Object);
```

Now `base.Init` will return `true` when called with `appContextMock`.

Note that you don't need your last null check (`this.myStateManager == null`) - the only way for `new IStateManager(this.myCommunication)` to fail, is to throw exception. If it does, it won't get to null check part anyways.